# Accessing and array and nested properties in Python

Tags: python, list, class, properties, nested

Sorry, I have searched and not managed to figure out an answer to this - I know there are lots of threads and questions in relation to it but cannot see an answer. Please redirect me or perhaps suggest a solution! TIA

I have an array of objects.
One (4 actually) of the properties of the objects in this array is another class.

Input taken from the user refers to one of the properties in the array which contains an instance of the other class. I simply want to read that data.

```
class direction():
    dest = -1
    lock = ''
class room():
    roomname = ''
    desc = ''
    n = direction()
    s = direction()
    w = direction()
    e = direction()
    item = ''

rooms = []
rooms.append( room() )
rooms.append( room() )
rooms.append( room() )
rooms.append( room() )
rooms.append( room() )

rooms[0].roomname = 'outside'
rooms[0].desc = ''
rooms[0].n.dest = 'bathroom'
rooms[0].item = ''

rooms[1].roomname = 'hall'
rooms[1].desc = 'The hallway has doors to the east and south'
rooms[1].s.dest = 2
rooms[1].e.dest = 3
rooms[1].item = ''
```

and so on..
Now I take input from the user eg: "go n"
and would like to check/read the 'lock' property from the property that relates to the taken direction in the current room. currentRoom is an integer that relates to the LIST element that it links to.

Please do not criticise my lack of constructors. I am trying to keep the code as simple as possible initially and will introduce those later on.

I take input as follows:

```
print('Your action:')
move = input('>>>').lower().split()
```

I use the following line of code to check that the taken direction exists in the current room as follows:

```
if getattr(rooms[currentRoom], move[1]) != '':
```

and then want to check the lock property for the given direction in the current room. Something like this... (which does not work)

```
if rooms[currentRoom].move[1].lock != '':
```

I hope this is clear enough! Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack! Could you add information about how the lock-property check doesn't work (actual and expected behaviors)?

Comment: I expect the code to return True if the lock property is not an empty string, instead I get an error as move[1] is evaluated as a string and not a property of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if rooms[currentRoom].move[1].lock != '':
```

This line of code will not work because `move[1]` is a string. If you wanted to access the variable in the class you would have to call it in the line of code

```
if rooms[currentRoom].n.lock != '':
```

A solution would be to get the value stored in the object then as follows

```
x = getattr(rooms[currentRoom], move[1]) #getattr() returns direction() object

if x.lock != '': #check lock value in direction() object
```

Comment: Thank you, of course! I feel silly now. I suppose it would be more complex to set the value of the attribute.